# Delete Function on the API Getaway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a partition key and a sort key on table (DynamoDB)

partition key: ClientID
sort key: CaseID

The Delete Code (Lambda):

```
    'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode = 0;
  
  const {ClientID} = event.pathParameters;
  const {CaseID} = event.pathParameters;

  const params = {
    TableName: "Case",
    Key: {
     ClientID: ClientID,
     CaseID: CaseID
    }
  };
  
  try {
    const data = await documentClient.delete(params).promise();
    responseBody = JSON.stringify(data.Items.key);
    statusCode = 204;
  } catch(err) {
    responseBody = `Unable to delete Case: ${err}`;
    statusCode = 403;
  }

  const response = {
    statusCode: statusCode,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "access-control-allow-origin":"*"
    },
    body: responseBody
  };

  return response;
};
```

If I try to delete element on API Getaway:

I got this error:

Status: 403
Unable to delete Case: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

How I can fix this error.

On The AWS Lambda with API Gateway:

I get this error:

Response
"errorType": "TypeError",
"errorMessage": "Cannot destructure property 'ClientID' of 'event.pathParameters' as it is undefined.",

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DynamoDB - Key element does not match the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506546/dynamodb-key-element-does-not-match-the-schema)

Comment: In the table schema, do the key names match your code? What types are ClientID and CaseID? In your code, do the same-named variables have matching types? Note: in modern JavaScript you can (and should) replace `ClientID: ClientID` with `ClientID`.

Comment: Yes the all 2 Key Have the same datatype ( String) , the same name on the DynamoDB

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `params`:

```
const params = {
    TableName: "Case",
    Key: {
     ClientID: ClientID,
     CaseID: CaseID
    }
  };
```

You have constants in your code with the same names as the `Key` portion of `params`, so it would be replaced with the constant's value. You should add quotes around your keys:

```
const params = {
    TableName: "Case",
    Key: {
     "ClientID": ClientID,
     "CaseID": CaseID
    }
  };
```

Option 2
I had a similar issue in Python, where I had to add types of data as well (basically it's DynamoDB JSON)

```
const params = {
    TableName: "Case",
    Key: {
     "ClientID": {"S": ClientID},
     "CaseID": {"S": CaseID}
    }
  };
```

Comment: I Try this did not work. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @MH check out option2. I had similar issues. Might be that it requires you to use the DynamoDB format of JSON

Comment: I Try option2, did not work. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) (for proxy integrations) pathParameters is null, so both ClientID and CaseID will come empty and you will get an error from DynamoDB, when you try to get an item. Examine the format of the input format and modify your code accordingly.