# how to get a certain item with secondary index

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I would like some help; i'm trying to get a certain item from the dynamodb table by calling it with the specific id (primary key) e with a global secondary index called index_book.

The function of interest is as follows:

```js
case "GET /book/{id}":
        body = await dynamo
          .get({
            TableName: "book",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        break;
```

The moment I go to call the url with a specific id, so for example /book/7 (where 7 is id)
I get the following error:

***"The provided key element does not match the schema"***

Can you help me please? I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886403/dynamodb-the-provided-key-element-does-not-match-the-schema did this help?

Comment: So you have sort key as well?

Comment: @Chetan already seen but this does not help

Comment: @Marcin no I only have a secondary index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do a get item against a GSI, you have to do a query. That's because in a GSI there's no uniqueness constraint and multiple items might have the same partition key / sort key combination.

So switch the get to a query and you'll also need to specify the IndexName.